# Media files are not displayed in the admin panel downloaded from the git repository

Tags: strapi

I immediately apologize for my English.

I am working on a Strapi project on several computers and use Git accordingly.

The public/uploads folder is uploaded to the Git repository along with all its contents.

To upload the changes, using the git pull command, I upload the changes.

All media files are uploaded to the folder of the same name, but they are not displayed in the administrative panel, the Image field is also empty in the resources I created.

How to solve this problem? In production, I'm going to store files in the same folder, without cloud services.

[Media Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89FQa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the "data.db" file from the .tmp folder did not get into the repository. After editing the file .gitignore everything has become as it should.